# What is the opposite of this data operation?

Tags: programming, c++, c, array, variables

If I store in an array a double-value in this format, in which format I should be able to read the same double out?

```
double myDouble = 12.123456;
byte myArray[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

myArray[0] = (myDouble >> 0);
myArray[1] = (myDouble >> 8);
myArray[2] = (myDouble >> 16);
myArray[3] = (myDouble >> 24);
```

Comment: Shifting a double? You don't really want to do that.

Comment: Please show the declarations of `myArray` and `myDouble` to show their exact type.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off making a union, that will be compiler independent, and won't give you the (possibly) odd results that trying to shift a double would give.

Example:

```
  union 
    {
    byte myArray [4];
    double myDouble;
    } foo;


   foo.myArray [0] = Serial.read ();
   foo.myArray [1] = Serial.read ();
   foo.myArray [2] = Serial.read ();
   foo.myArray [3] = Serial.read ();

   double f = foo.myDouble;
```

Even then be cautious that whatever is sending you this double in 4 bytes is using the same encoding for doubles that the Arduino does. For one thing, **double** and **float** are the same on the 8-bit Arduinos (they are only 4 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

in the simplest form (compiler dependent however), a pointer will do.

Comment: Would you mind developing your answer further, so that we can clearly see how it really answers the OP question?